# Flex: Simultaneous touch in one app?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5, multi-touch

I have an app with several buttons running on a touch screen (Windows 7) - can I make the app respond to a user touching 2 different buttons at the same time? Or will only one of the buttons respond?

I don't need any gestures and have set the inputmode to touch_point. My test shows that it supports touch events and have 10 max touch points. But to add touch_tap to the buttons does not make both buttons react.

Any hints would be most apreciated!

Comment: I didn't think a button 'responded' until the 'touch-Up' event; smilar to how the button doesn't erspond to a click until mouse up.  What do you expect to happen when two buttons are both touched simultaneously?  Wouldn't you have to set the input mode to Multitouch? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Multitouch.html

Comment: Touch tap is touch begin and touch end so that should not make a difference? I would like the buttons to run whatever code on click/tap, but currently only one of them does. I was thinking Multitouch was for gestures (I don't need that), so I was using TOUCH_POINT. Is that wrong?

Comment: I managed to get it working at last. I used touch end on the buttons and inputmode touch_point. Not really sure why it wasn't working before :)